# grails test-app -xml -coverage attempts to resolve XML URIs and times out

Tags: xml, grails, groovy, cobertura

I'm behind a proxy, and I need `grails test-app -xml -coverage` to NOT resolve whatever XML field it's trying to resolve and not connect to the internet.

Any idea how to get this working? I need the proxy to *not* be set for the tests to work.

Comment: Is this still a problem? Looks like they resolved http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPCODECOVERAGE-35

Comment: Indeed it has, Rob. If post that as an answer, I'll delete my own and accept and upvote yours.

Comment: Nah, your answer's good. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @Rob Hruska's comment, this has been resolved.

[JIRA issue](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPCODECOVERAGE-35)